# Regex capture string between delimiter including the last delimited group

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string in the following format:

```
ignorethis_capture1_capture2_[more captured groups]
```

The string to be matched is delimited by `'_'`. I need to get all the matched strings separately except the `'ignorethis'` string which is always at the beginning. I can delimit by `'_'` but then have a problem with getting the last captured group.

eg string: **start_data1_data2_data3**

should give: **data1**, **data2**, **data3** as matched groups

Thanks in advance

UPDATE: I know this can be done using string split. I was just befuddled as to how to do such an operation using regex so thought to ask here

Comment: Can someone please provide an explanation as to what's wrong with the question and how I can improve it rather than just red arrowing it

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```js
var s = 'start_data1_data2_data3';
re = /_([^_]+)/g;
result = [];
while (m = re.exec(s))  {
  result.push(m[1]);
}
document.write(result.join(','));
```

Comment: Ahh. I see it now. I need to remember to use global modifier :) Thanks so much

Comment: Without global modifier, regex will stop at the first match.

Comment: Yes. I wasn't going about thinking in that way which made seem it harder than it really is

Answer (score 2):

You don't need regex:

```js
var s = 'start_data1_data2_data3';

alert(s.split('_').slice(1));
```

Comment: Yes. But this is out of my own sheer curiosity :) I want to see how regex would work in such a case